# GoLang | SQLC | How to log SQL queries when invoked using fmt

Tags: go, sqlc

How to log SQLC queries with the values passed to the receiver functions?

What I'm thinking is to get the constant variable of the query and format it using a function.

Is there any easier way or SQLC feature for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Update: My solution is not possible because the constant variable that contains the query is not exported.